# What's the difference between the SharedAccessBlobPermissions values Add, Create and Write?

Tags: azure, permissions, authorization, azure-blob-storage

The possible values for [`SharedAccessBlobPermissions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.sharedaccessblobpermissions) are:

- None (0)
- Read (1)
- Write (2)
- Delete (4)
- List (8)
- Add (16)
- Create (32)

What are the differences between `Add`, `Create` and `Write`? I can't find any documentation that clarifies this.

Comment: By looking on the names logically and without knowing anything about Azure, my guess would be that Add adds an existing element to a set, Create creates an element which does not exist yet and maybe adds it as well and Write writes something.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! A comment is well... A comment and not a reply. If I wanted to reply, I would have replied. As about getting points, please read a little about this site before you make premature assumptions. While it is good to see new people on stack overflow, we try to maintain the high level of this site and, accordingly, I have flagged your comment as it was not really constructive. Since you have refused my goodwill with your comment, I concluded that your question is beyond repair and voted to close it.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can find information about these permissions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn140255.aspx.

From what I understand reading about these permissions:

- **Add**: Add permission is only applicable for append blobs. You use this permission to add a block to an append blob. No other operation is possible using this permission.
- **Create**: Create permission only allows creation of blobs or in other words you can't update a blob with this permission. This would include writing a new blob, take a snapshot of an existing blob, or copy a blob to a new blob.
- **Write**: Write permission allows creation and updation of blobs. This would include create or write content, properties, metadata, or block list, take a snapshot or manage lease on a blob and resize the blob (page blob only).

In our application, we use Shared Access Signature extensively and we make use of `Write` permission almost exclusively on all the blob related operations.

Comment: Thank you, Gaurav. That link shows permissions for all types of Azure objects, I can see the distinctions now!

Comment: Note Write also includes the ability to overwrite, whereas Create does not.